# Paypal connection error SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

Tags: ssl, curl, paypal, openssl, php-openssl

I'm using PHP SDK integration with Paypal REST API.
My installation works on my LAMP server with PHP v7.0.22 and OpenSSL module v.1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016

Sometimes I'm experiencing a connection error to Paypal:

```
ERROR - 2018-11-25 17:45:05.3378400 - PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 in ../lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 ../lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(73): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('')
```

Looking into PayPalHttpConnection seems a curl error, but I cannot find a solution.
I want to underline that this is a random error, but most of time the connection works.

Comment: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1689

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-02/0017.html.  Seems like this is associated with OpenSSL.

Comment: errno 104 is ECONNRESET - the server has closed the connection. It is not a problem caused by the client and there is likely nothing you can do on the client side except to retry.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if it is a good idea to retry the payment excecution because I could not be sure that the request was not received by Paypal...